# removeElementsInSetDecrementsSize test not going through with HashTable

Tags: java, junit, hashtable

I have one test that is not going through in this testclass. I have implemented the code that I have tried, however it is not working. I dont know what I am doing wrong. I think that my Hashtable code is correct however, this test does not work.

//TODO: How should I write this test in the testclass.

The message I get is :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: <7>
     but: was <0>
Expected :<7>
Actual   :<0>
```

```
/**
 * An interface describing a generic set. Duplicates are not allowed.
 */
public interface Set<T> {

    boolean add(T elem);

    boolean remove(T elem);

    boolean contains(T elem);

    int size();
}
```

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import static java.util.Objects.hash;

/**
 * A hash table-based implementation of the Set interface.
 */
public class HashSet<T> implements Set<T> {
   private List<T>[] table;
    private int size;
    private int capacity;
    private int index;



     /**
     * Creates a hash table with the given capacity (amount of buckets).
     *
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if capacity <= 0.
     */
    public HashSet(int capacity) {
        if (capacity <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "capacity must be a positive, non-zero value! Provided: " + capacity);
        }
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // for this declaration only
      List<T>[] t = new LinkedList[capacity];
      table = t;
      size = 0;
    }


    /**
     * Adds the given element to the set.
     *
     * Complexity: O(1) expected time.
     *
     * @param elem An element to add to the set.
     * @return true if the set did not contain the element, otherwise false.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean add(T elem) {
    if (elem == null || elem.equals("")){
            return false;
        }

        int hash = Math.abs(elem.hashCode() % table.length);

        if (table[hash]== null){
            table[hash] = new LinkedList<T>();
            table[hash].add(elem);
            size ++;
            return true;
        }
        if (table[hash].contains(elem)){
            return false;
        }else{
            table[hash].add(elem);
            size++;
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes the given element from the dictionary, if it is present.
     *
     * Complexity: O(1) expected time.
     *
     * @param elem An element to remove from the set.
     * @return true if the set contained the element, false otherwise.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean remove(T elem) {
        if (elem == null || elem.equals("")){
            return false;
        }

        int hash = Math.abs(elem.hashCode() % table.length);

        if (table[hash] != null && table[hash].contains(elem)){
            table[hash].remove(elem);
            size --;
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Check if an element is in the Set.
     *
     * Complexity: O(1) expected time.
     *
     * @param elem An element to look for.
     * @return true if the element is in the set, false otherwise.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean contains(T elem) {
        if (elem == null || elem .equals("")){
            return false;
        }
        int hash = Math.abs(elem.hashCode() % table.length);

        if (table[hash] != null && table[hash].contains(elem)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        HashSet<?> hashSet = (HashSet<?>) o;
        return capacity == hashSet.capacity && size == hashSet.size && index == hashSet.index && Objects.equals(table, hashSet.table);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return hash(capacity, size, index, table);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of elements in this set.
     *
     * Complexity: O(1) expected time.
     *
     * @return The amount of elements in this set.
     */
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.rules.Timeout;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.EmptyStackException;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
/**
 * Abstract test class for Set implementations.
 *
 * Implementing test classes must override the getIntegerSet method.
 *
 */
public abstract class SetTest {
    @Rule public Timeout globalTimeout = Timeout.seconds(5); // 5 seconds max per method tested

    private Set<Integer> set;
    private final int CAPACITY = 20;
    private int[] uniqueSetElements;
    private int[] elementsNotInSet;

    /**
     * Returns an implementation of Set that can hold at least 'minCapacity'
     * Integers.
     *
     * @param minCapacity The least amount of elements the Set must be able to
     * hold.
     * @return An implementation of Set.
     */
    protected abstract Set<Integer> getIntegerSet(int minCapacity);

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // Arrange
        set = getIntegerSet(CAPACITY);
        uniqueSetElements =
            new int[] {-234, 32, 443, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE, 0, -231};
        // Works because all elements in uniqueSetElements are more than 2 values apart
        // -2 as Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1 == Integer.MAX_VALUE because of underflow
        elementsNotInSet = Arrays.stream(uniqueSetElements).map(elem -> elem - 2).toArray();

        for (int elem : uniqueSetElements) {
            set.add(elem);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void removeElementsInSetDecrementsSize() { //TEST
        int expectedSize = uniqueSetElements.length;
        for (int elem : uniqueSetElements) {
            // Act
            set.remove(elem);
        }
        assertThat(set.size(), equalTo(expectedSize));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are removing all elements from the set and still expecting the size to be the original size. Set `expectedSize` to 0 and it would be fine.

```java
@Test
    public void removeElementsInSetDecrementsSize() { //TEST
        int expectedSize = 0;
        for (int elem : uniqueSetElements) {
            // Act
            set.remove(elem);
        }
        assertThat(set.size(), equalTo(expectedSize));
    }
```